# PostgreSQL how to build a query which updates data to an existing table but to avoid duplicate value in a specific column

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build a very specific PSQL query that has to update a table data adding to a column called `sign_order` a number that identifies an order of an entity called `recipient` to sign a document.

To be clear but out of scope is that there is a document that has recipients and the recipients they have to sign that order on a specific order.

I tried initially the following query but the issue is that works if we have no data on the table but soon as it runs on a table filled it generates duplicates for the same type

```js
UPDATE
  recipients
SET
  sign_order = CASE
    "role"
    WHEN 'CONSENTEE' THEN 1
    WHEN 'GUARDIAN' THEN 2
    WHEN 'ASSENTEE' THEN 3
    WHEN 'COUNTERSIGNEE' THEN 4
  END
WHERE
  "role" IN ('CONSENTEE', 'GUARDIAN', 'ASSENTEE', 'COUNTERSIGNEE');

ALTER TABLE recipients ALTER COLUMN sign_order SET NOT NULL;
```

So what happening here is that is adding the signed order when it finds the case but creates a duplicate for example if that finds already a `Guardian` it ads as 2 but for the same document we can have multiple `Guardian` and we have an issue as that is added as Guardian 2 then Guardian 2 but should be Guardian 2 Guardian 3 and so on.

The same affects the rest.

A view of the issue where the recipients under the same document are assigned with the same signing order:

```
select consentee_id, "role" , count(*)
from recipients
group by "role", consentee_id
order by "count" desc;
```

Result

[image]

The base case order is as in the query;

```sh
1 CONSENTEE
2 GUARDIAN
3 ASSENTEE
4 COUNTERSIGNEE
```

This order needs to be maintained and as an example of the right output running the query should be:

| recipient | sign_order |
| --- | --- |
| CONSENTEE | 1 |
| GUARDIAN | 2 |
| GUARDIAN | 3 |
| GUARDIAN | 4 |
| ASSENTEE | 5 |
| COUNTERSIGNEE | 6 |
| COUNTERSIGNEE | 7 |
| COUNTERSIGNEE | 8 |

I need to add 2 constraints as `unique` for these `consentee_id` and `sign_order` and then make the query more complex to solve the problem described.

The `ALTER` part I believe with the constraints will look as it is

```
ALTER TABLE recipients ALTER COLUMN sign_order SET NOT NULL 
AND
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_sign_order UNIQUE (consentee_id, sign_order);
```

However, need some help to achieve the goal of this solving problem issue.

Update to give a better view of the table

[image]

Table properties

[image]

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE public.recipients (
    id text NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    email text NULL,
    phone text NULL,
    locale text NULL,
    consentee_id text NULL,
    is_primary bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    sign_order int4 NOT NULL,
    "role" text NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT recipients_id_unique UNIQUE (id),
    CONSTRAINT recipients_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT recipients_consentee_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (consentee_id) REFERENCES public.consentees(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: If there are multiple guardians, by what do you determine the order in which they come?

Comment: The gurdians are created one by one from an input form in the front end and what determine which first is the created at. However, the guardians it self they not have a strict order they can sign whatever order. The real order between the roles which they need to be maintained. I hope this answers the question

Comment: So then use @Belayer's approach with `row_number()` but add the `created_at` column to the `order by` clause, after the role.

Comment: Yes seems reasonable I'm waiting for @Belayer to have a last word after my updates but seems that we are very close to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some as yet unmentioned unique column (PK perhaps) you can assign the `sign_order` value in a CTE, then the main portion of the query updates the column for the PK. I've also assumed your table also contains more that 1 document to be signed (if not it a pretty limited table) with its own signing order. In the following these column are *id* and *doc_id* respectively. If those assumptions are invalid, well do not know if this will work.  
The big change from what you had was to move the CASE expression into an order by clause of a row_number window function. Then assign sort_order from the row_number value and that is a CTE. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aad7e688250b1b32b4511928c441a370))

```
with assign_sign_order ( rid, sorder) as  
     ( select id, row_number() over (partition by doc_id 
                                         order by 
                                               case "role"
                                                    when 'CONSENTEE' then 1
                                                    when 'GUARDIAN'  then 2
                                                    when 'ASSENTEE'  then 3
                                                    when 'COUNTERSIGNEE' then 4
                                                end
                                      ) so
                                      , "role", doc_id
         from recipients order by id 
     ) 
update recipients r
   set sign_order = s.sorder
  from assign_sign_order s 
 where r.id = s.rid ;
```

An alternative would be to create a ENUM for the "role", this simplifies the above query, and would reduce maintenance to just updating the ENUM (no change to the query). Providing you do not want to remove one. It is also in the demo.

Comment: Thank you and hope with my comment can give you a better understanding and maybe change the answer. The table I need to make the update is called recipients.
The doc table is something else. We have a primary entity which is the consented and under that we the rest of the roles. They are related via the conesntee_id. All the roles under the same consentee_id are about the same. I made a doc to explain more please have a look https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sr3yFXLwlurAyJWkcchBPsY3e6qkBUizESN8v-sXuds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please update your question and post the actual table definition (ddl), including Priamry and Foreign keys.  I do not think there is a great deal to change, but actual table definition will clear up a couple questions. I will take a longer look later.

Comment: I updated with extra info please have a look

Comment: just a heads up, in my DDL the signed order is NOT NULL because this is the new column how should be in the end. Obviously in the beginning is NULL then data is added then is set to NOT NULL. Added this to have no confusion about the table.

Comment: The answer helped me and I had only to add the `created_at` as suggested in comments for the rest only a few name changes to be adapted to my original table.
But the answer was really good.